# Elastic Search: Unable to retrieve yesterday's and today's records

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, publish-subscribe

I am trying to query an elk cluster through a subscription method but it does not return today's and yesterday's record. This is the function that does a POST request to the cluster, I use **_search** at the end of the url in order to perform the search:

```
 getIncomingMessages(from:Number, size:Number, fromTime: String, toTime:String, sort:String){

 let query= { "query": {
  "bool": {
      "must": [
          {
              "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": fromTime,
                       "lte":  toTime
                  }
              }
          },
          {
              "query_string": {
                  "query": "json.message:incoming"
              }
          }
      ]
  }},"sort": [
{
  "@timestamp": {
    "order": sort
  }
}], "from": from, "size": size} return this.http.post(this.url1, query) //url1 is just the url of the cluster
```

This is the subscription method:

```
getIncomingMessages(from:Number, size:Number, fromDate: String, toDate:String, sort:String){

this.inObs = this.dataService.getIncomingMessages(from, size, fromDate, toDate, sort).subscribe(data =>{
 
  let msg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  for(let hit in msg.hits.hits){
    this.incomingMessages.push(msg.hits.hits[hit]["_source"]["json"]["message"])
    this.incomingMessagesApp.push(msg.hits.hits[hit]["_source"]["app_name"])
    let  msgdate =msg.hits.hits[hit]["_source"]["@timestamp"]
    let date = new Date(msgdate)
    this.incomingMsgDates.push(date)
   
    //console.log(msg.hits.hits[hit]["_id"])
  }

  console.log(data)
 
  
  
},
error=>{
  console.log(error)
})   }
```

I call this subscription method inside ngOnInit():

```
toDate:Date = new Date()
  fromDate:Date = new Date(new Date().setDate(this.fromDate.getDate()-1)) //yesterday's date
this.getIncomingMessages(0, 10, this.fromDate.toISOString(),this.toDate.toISOString(), "desc"  )
```

Is it something to do with the subscription promises by any chance? This is my first time working with Angular and Elk so any kind guidance would be helpful!

Comment: Your query looks ok, but shouldn't `"gte": "fromTime"` be `"gte": fromTime,`? i.e. you seem to be sending the string `"fromTime"` instead of what's referenced by the parameter `fromTime`... Same for `toTime`

Comment: @Val Sorry that was a mistake while writing the question here, I've edited it now.